# An extension of a corollary of the Arzela-Ascoli theorem for smooth functions

Tags: proof-verification, uniform-convergence, arzela-ascoli

I'm trying generalize [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1559479/if-all-derivative-are-uniformly-bounded-there-is-a-subsequence-that-converges-u?noredirect=1&lq=1) corollary for the case which the sequence of functions $\{ f_n \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ are defined on a bounded domain (open and connected) $U \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ ($m \geq 2$). I would like to know how I can prove this or if I need put some restrictions on more to this statement be true.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After do some research, I found [this lecture notes](http://www.math.utk.edu/~freire/teaching/m447f16/SpacesDifferentiableMaps.pdf), which pratically solves the problem as we can see by the proofs of the lemma and of the proposition $2$ of this notes. Applying the Arzela Ascoli theorem a countable number of times as it was applied on proposition $2$, we develop a countable collection of subsequences of our original sequence and remains apply a standard diagonal argument (the same argument which is used on the [proof of Arzela Ascoli theorem](https://users.math.msu.edu/users/shapiro/Pubvit/Downloads/ArzNotes/ArzNotes.pdf)) in order to ensure that the uniform limit of the sequence $(f_n)$ is differentiable, i.e., if $f_n \rightarrow f$, then $f \in \mathcal{C}^{\infty}(U)$.